# Is it posible to run some case tests from a file using codeblocks without using file functions

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, testcase

I have the following tests below in a file and I want to run these tests but i do not want to type all of them and neither change my code which is using scanf to fscanf to read from a file, is it possible using CodeBlocks?

```
Sample Input 

2
3
a b c A B C
a:BAC
b:BAC
c:ACB
A:acb
B:bac
C:cab
3
a b c A B C
a:ABC
b:ABC
c:BCA
A:bac
B:acb
C:abc
```

Comment: Put the data in a file, and redirect your program's standard input to that file? Not sure how much (if anything) Code::Blocks does to support doing that when you run the program from inside the IDE though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using terminal and stream redirection and pipes.
Here's some link from google assuming you are using linux: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection

You probably need something like this (pipe):

```
$ cat your_file | your_binary
```

or (stream)

```
$ your_binary < your_file
```

Comment: I am using Windows, but using your words i googled and found this website which explains. PS: When i use Linux i will try that. Thanks http://zhukovc.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/input-redirection.html